# What is the word for wanting something bad to happen to yourself?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I once saw a word that means "wanting something bad to happen to yourself", and I can't seem to find it again. They described it as wanting to get in a car accident or get really sick.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, there's "self-loathing", but that doesn't imply wanting have something bad happen.

Comment: Self-destructive?

Comment: Bad as in naughty/in a sick manner? Or bad as in damaging or suicidal

Comment: @Ingrid (check comment above)

Comment: Munchausen syndrome kind of touches on this.

Answer (score 1):

***masochistic***

> masochism: *Psychoanalysis* the directing toward oneself of any destructive tendencies [Collins Discovery Encyclopedia](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/masochist)

Answer (score 0):

> Passive suicidal ideation

"...the wish to die during sleep, to be killed in an accident, or to develop terminal cancer..."

http://www.currentpsychiatry.com/the-publication/issue-single-view/passive-suicidal-ideation-still-a-high-risk-clinical-scenario/651a76321f5ec282d271b194343a9bfd.html

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comments above. **Suicidal** seems to fit the bill well (since a person wants to get in a car accident):

> wanting to kill yourself

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/suicidal))

A softer word would be **self-destructive**:

> deliberately doing things that are likely to **seriously harm** or **kill yourself**

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/self-destructive))

Answer (score 0):

If you'd take a phrase instead of a word, I'd go with "glutton for punishment". Still, this means more like trying over and over to get something one wants DESPITE the fact that bad things keep happening in attempting the pursuit. So Elian is probably right: it's masochistic.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found the word **Lachesism** in this [buzzfeed article](http://www.buzzfeed.com/danieldalton/my-pain-has-a-name), which defines it as "the desire to be struck by disaster - to survive a plane crash, or to lose everything in a fire". As far as I can tell it is a word made up by this [Tumblr](http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/post/64620271186/lachesism) blog.